# how to show the dtstart and until using rrule plugin from daterange in fullcalendar 5

Tags: fullcalendar, rrule

I am using fullcalendar 5 and when using `eventClick` i want to show the `dtstart` and `until` values from a recurrent event. I am using the rrule plugin.
When i click on asingle event, this gives me the data from `start`:

```
eventClick:  function(info) {

alert(info.event.startStr); // something like 2021-05-04
```

but in case it is a recurrent event which has a date range from lets say `2021-05-01 till 2021-07-01`
and the first occurrence appears on `2021-05-05`, the alert show me this date (2021-05-05) and i want to show me the date of the start of the recurrence, so `2021-05-01`. Really don't know how to get the startdate and enddate of the range from an recurrent event when i use the `evenClick function` in combination with rrule plugin...

Can someone help me with that?